# How to reduce compilation time using pickle by saving trained model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk, text-classification, naivebayes

This is a sentiment analysis code and every time I change my input, it takes 10-15 mins to compile. What are the ways in which I can reduce it? Using pickle by saving the classifier or any other method is preferable?
Other functions are not mentioned here.

```
inpTweets = csv.reader(open('training_neatfile_4.csv', 'r' ,encoding='ISO-8859-1'), delimiter=',')
stopWords = getStopWordList('stopwords.txt')
count = 0;
featureList = []
tweets = []
for row in inpTweets:
    sentiment = row[0]
    tweet = row[1]
    processedTweet = processTweet(tweet)
    featureVector = getFeatureVector(processedTweet, stopWords)
    featureList.extend(featureVector)
    tweets.append((featureVector, sentiment));
#end loop

# Remove featureList duplicates
featureList = list(set(featureList))

# Generate the training set
training_set = nltk.classify.util.apply_features(extract_features, tweets)

# Train the Naive Bayes classifier
nb_classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)

# Test the classifier
testTweet = 'He is a brainless kid'
processedTestTweet = processTweet(testTweet)
sentiment = nb_classifier.classify(extract_features(getFeatureVector(processedTestTweet, stopWords)))
print ("testTweet = %s, sentiment = %s\n" % (testTweet, sentiment))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Training a NaiveBayesClassifier(or any) takes a lot of time(depends on the feeding of training data), it becomes easier if you save the object of classifier(NBClassifier) once you've trained it to save time by omitting re-training.

Following is the way to save objects using pickle, you may use it in your code to save train or load the Classifier.

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(object, file)
```

You may save NaiveBayesClassifier by saving its object(nb_classifier) as following.

```
with open('model.pkl', 'wb') as nb_classifier_model:
    pickle.dump(nb_classifier, nb_classifier_model)
```

Then, you can retrieve it as:

```
with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as nb_classifier_model:
    nb_classifier = pickle.load(nb_classifier_model)
```

That is how you may achieve your goal by using accordingly.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But what object should I pass in pickle.dump() ?

Comment: I've already mentioned this in the example code, pass NBClassifier, as it is used to classify the tweet according to your code i.e., `NBClassifier.classify()`

Comment: @A.Bora you may have confused yourself because you did not follow the Python conventions for variable naming. `NBClassifier` in your question is not a type, but an object of type `NaiveBayesClassifier`. Call it `nb_classifier` (or whatever) and the code will be clearer.

Comment: @abhinav, for the same reason, your code is confusing to readers. It looks as if you're dumping the classifier _class_, but of course the trained object is being dumped. I recommend you edit your answer to clarify. (I'd use appropriate capitalization, even if it doesn't match the variable names in the question.)

Comment: @alexis, do you know why isn't there a `Classifier.save()` method?

Comment: @alexis Thanks for your insight.